# Tried building a query that would give you the page views per url for a given date range and needs to apply filters in query builder

Tags: python, django, pandas, google-analytics, google-reporting-api

I got the output for the page views per url for a given date range but as it fetches every url i need to apply filters into it for the dimension **ga:landingPagePath**

The output for the query when executed is:-
[image]

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html

And i only need the pageviews for the landing page starting with **/job-details/**
[image]

I tried giving the filters like:-

**filters=ga:landingPagePath%3D%3D/job-details/**

but i was getting an error like:-

**Error message: Invalid value 'filters=ga:landingPagePath%3D%3D/job-details/'. Values must match the following regular expression: 'ga:.+'**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ga:landingPagePath==/job-details/256135